# Stuck creating p12 file for MoonAPNS

Tags: ios, ssl, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, moonapns

I am having some trouble creating my .p12 certificate. 
I have previously created an application with push notification, this works fine. 
The application takes the users device id and saves it into a database.

I have added the code into my new application(with the amendments to work with the new application), and from the Log it seems to be working in the same way as my other app.

I have downloaded the relevant files that i need and then i know i needed to use ssl to be able to create my new and combined p12. 
I cant for the life of me remember how i created the p.12 file.

I'm using moonapns.

I have used the following:

> Step 1:
>
> openssl x509 -in aps_developer_identity.cer -inform DER -out
>   aps_developer_identity.pem -outform PEM}
>
> Where aps_developer_identity.cer is the file you download from the
>   portal
>
> Step 2:
>
> openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out APSCertificates.pem -in
>   APSCertificates.p12
>
> Where APSCertificates.p12 is a file you export from the Mac Keychain.
>   This is critical, you must import the certificate from the portal into
>   keychain. Find it in My Certificates, open the disclosure triangle and
>   highlight both the certificate and the private key, then right click
>   and export them. Give them a password and save them to a p12 file.
>
> Step 3:
>
> openssl pkcs12 -export -in aps_developer_identity.pem -out
>   aps_developer_identity.p12 -inkey APSCertificates.pem

I have added the certificate and it isn't working, i'm not receiving the notification to the device. Does any one know how else i am supposed to create the certificate??

Comment: Try to restart your xcode after the installation of files

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 check this tutorial

Comment: @sabeer i have tried that but it only creates a pem file i then need to convert that back to a p12 file for windows and this is where i get stuck?

Comment: I did get the same case, it was only valid for one apps, but when i tried to generate another certificate(s) it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in your_app.pem -inkey your_key.pem -out your_app_key.p12
```

refer this link 
    http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=7468

Comment: I took a look at the link, thank you. Do you mean that i need to type the following line into terminal before combining the two pem files into one pem file? and not use the line "$ cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem"

Comment: I Tried again and still no luck? is there any other ideas that could be the problem maybe?

Comment: Has it solved yet ? if it were solved, please tell me what was the main problem, i got the same case :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

After downloading the .cer file (aps_development certificate is not the ios_development), manages the pem file with the following command:

```
openssl x509 -in "path_to_apple_cert.cer" -inform DER -out "path_to_an_output_Cert.pem" -outform PEM
```

Take your APSCertificates.p12 file and run the second command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in "path_to_exported_p12_from_apple_cer.p12" -out "path_to_an_output_Key.pem" -passin pass:your_p12_password -passout pass:your_new_p12_password
```

Now take the two pem files that you generated and run the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey "path_to_an_output_Key.pem" -in "path_to_an_output_Cert.pem" -out "path_to_final_p12.p12" -passin pass:your_new_p12_password -passout pass:your_final_p12_password
```

This is your P12 for push notifications.

If you do not want to use the

```
$ cat command PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem
```

contained in some instances, if you are on windows you can use:

```
type PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck.pem
```