# IOS - Push Notification Certificate Doesn't Work

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I have an annoying problem since a month ago. Let me introduce the problem.
Several weeks ago i got 2 similar projects, and each of them would be implementing push notification. Say the app's name were AB and DC.
So i tried to find out some articles about push notification, and i found http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1. At the first time i was implementing the Push Notification on the AB project, and it was going well, it was well done at the first-try. Then i did the same things, I did couple of steps for DC project. And it didn't work (DC Project). I had just copied the same code i've used in AB to the DC project, and it didn't work (DC Project). The codes were similar. As before I thought that i missed any single code, so i used the AB certificate in DC project, and it worked but the notification was sent for AB project, then i thought the DC code was correctly written. Does anyone of you know what has been going wrong ?

FYI :

For AB Project (worked)
- I was using Development Cert

System and Tools
- XCODE 5
- For Push Agent I was using C# (MoonAPNS)

I think i have the similar problem with this thread
[Stuck creating p12 file for MoonAPNS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956915/stuck-creating-p12-file-for-moonapns?rq=1)
but the referred thread hasn't been answered yet.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: are you using exactly the same bundle IDs?

Comment: No they aren't, they are standing for different bundle IDs.

Answer (score -1):

You have to check following points:
1. Bundle Identifier of the registered appId and that used in xcode.
2. Check if certificates are made correct (provisioning profiles, app Id etc.)
3. Refresh the provisioning profile after making certificate and run the application in test device (not in simulator).
4. Check port number you are using for connection.

I think your problem is due to second point.

Comment: i think i have checked it at all sir, the bundle are separated correctly, so 1 and 2 should be cleared sufficiently. I have followed the couple of steps similarly as i've had before, so i did the same steps. 3. I don't know how to refresh the prov profile, 4. the port number should be cleared enough, i could connect to the apple server.

Comment: Refreshing means once you have made certificate for APNS, then now you need to download and install the provisioning profile again to get APNS notifications.